# Can I bring a GPU in my carry on from the USA to Chile?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, airport-security

Last time I had a GPU brought from the US it was my brother-in-law who put it in his suitcase and when he landed in Chile he noticed that at the US Customs they opened it and opened the GPU box, leaving a piece of paper saying that they were checking if it was a bomb or something similar (Thankfully they didn't break it)

Now I'll be travelling on April this year to the US and I want to buy a new graphics card over there. Is it safe to bring it in my carry on? Will I have any trouble at the airport security? (I would be going back from the US to Chile)

Please excuse my english, and thanks for your help!!